# Angular 2 material md-input validation

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-material

I'm using the md-input component of material for Angular 2. I know it's still a alpha version of material but maybe someone could explain me how to use the html validation attribute required of Angular 2 with md-input(Is it implemented yet?). I have tried this(works fine):

```
<md-card>
    <md-input 
        placeholder="Url"
        id="url"
        url="url"
        [(ngModel)]="urlInputValue"
        #url="ngModel"
        required>
        <md-hint *ngIf="url.errors && (url.dirty || url.touched)" [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red'}"> Url is required </md-hint>            
    </md-input>

    <button
        md-raised-button color="accent"
        [disabled]="isUrlInputEmpty()"
        (click)="onRequestBtnClick()">
        Request
    </button>
</md-card>
```

How I can use 'required'?

```
<md-hint *ngIf="url.errors.required && (url.dirty || url.touched)" [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red'}"> Url is required </md-hint>
```

Comment: you want a control over the md-input or just you want that it should be required ?

Comment: It should be required. When I use url.errors.required instead of url.errors I get "Cannot read property 'required' of null" error message.

Comment: yes , normally , what do you have in the `url` in the TS part ? and normally if  it is mentioned `required` in the `md-input` element it should be required.

Comment: I implemented nothing specific for the url in the ts file. Just declared the 'urlInputValue' property. I think I need a container(div?) to prevent the null error of the url.errors.required. How can I do that with md-input?

Comment: Do you know `FromGroup` module ?

Answer (score 2):

In your TS file you should have :

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class UrlComponent  {   
   public urlForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  this.urlForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  url:    new FormControl('', Validators.required),
   });
  }
//... codes..
}
```

And change your HTML to :

```
<form role="form" [formGroup]="urlForm" novalidate>
<md-input 
    placeholder="Url"
    id="url"
    url="url"
    [(ngModel)]="urlInputValue"
    formControlName="url"
    #url="ngModel"
     >
    <md-hint *ngIf="url.errors && (url.dirty || url.touched)" [ngStyle]="{'color': 'red'}"> Url is required </md-hint>            
</md-input>

<button
    md-raised-button color="accent"
    [disabled]="isUrlInputEmpty()"
    (click)="onRequestBtnClick()">
    Request
</button>

</form>
```

Comment: this is reactive form approach
how to to it using template driver approach ?